# In plotly how do I specify absolute colors?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I'm using `plotly.graphic_objects` to draw a Treemap:

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go

go.Figure(go.Treemap(
        labels=["red", "green", "blue", "white", "black"],
        parents=["", "", "", "", ""],
        values=[1,1,1,1,1],
        marker=dict(
            colors=["#ff0000", "#00ff00", "#0000ff", "#ffffff", "#000000"],
            ),
        )).show()
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

So despite I've specified `#ffffff` for "white" and `#000000` for "black" both colors are being changed (*normalized*?) to some light-grayish color.

"blue", which should be colored `#0000ff` looks bleached, too.

Is there a way to make those colors being interpreted as "absolute" colors?

Comment: I ran your code and I can see black and white correctly rendered.

Comment: Na you can actually use `colors=["red", "green", "blue", "white", "black"]`

Comment: same result when I use "white" and "black"

Comment: which version of plotly do you use? It's 4.9.0 for me  (I wrote 1.3.3 before but that was a mistake)